# change windows phone 8.1 date/time

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8.1

anyone made code that change date/time on windows phone 8.1?
I couldn't find any thing on how to change date/time
in windows phone using 3rd party app, is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a Win32 call in older versions of Windows but a function to set date or time doesn't seem to be supported in Windows Phone 8.1.

[List of supported Win32 API in Windows Runtime Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx).